# C#. How to connect 2 mqtt-broker in one program?

Tags: c#, mqtt

**I'm trying to use 2 MQTT broker in one program with C#**.
I'm using 'M2MQTT.Net' library to use MQTT application in my program.

First of all, I succeed to make single MQTT connection with broker.
Also, succeed to subscribe & publish with topic.

```
// Simple code that i make single connection with broker.
private void InitMqtt()
    {
        MqttClient = new MqttClient(brokerAddr);
    }

// MqttClinet() method in the M2MQTT.Net library, MQTTClient class.
public MqttClient(string brokerHostName)
        : this(brokerHostName, 1883, secure: false, null, null, MqttSslProtocols.None)
    {
    }
```

**So what if i want to make MQTT connection over than 1, is this right code?**

```
private void InitMqtt()
    {
        MqttClient = new MqttClient(brokerAddr);
        MqttClient2 = new MqttClient(brokerAddr2);
        MqttClient3 = new MqttClient(brokerAddr3);
    }
```

If it's possible to make multi-connection with various mqtt broker,
can i handle the events from 3 brokers individually?
Thanks for reading. Regards.

Comment: You can connect as many clients as you want. Just make sure they are not on the same  thread. Not sure how your library works, but I believe it depends on how you handle messages and not how you initialize client itself.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any problem if i use them on the same thread? The 'thread' you said means C#'s thread function or just meaning about preventing crash among them?

Comment: Apparently, I might have stated wrong about threading, seems like your provided library works asynchronously so basically you should have no problem of using multiple clients as you would use one client.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to connect multi Clients to Multi Brokers in a single task, but each Mqtt client has its own callbacks method. Somethings like this:

```
    protected MyMqttClient(string name ,MqttClientOptions options, List<string> TopicFiletrs)
    {
        //this._name = $"{GetType().Name}({name})";
        this._name = name;
        var factory = new MqttFactory();
        _client = factory.CreateMqttClient();
        
        _client.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync += _client_ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync;
        _client.ConnectedAsync += _client_ConnectedAsync;
        _client.DisconnectedAsync += _client_DisconnectedAsync;

        _options = options;
        _TopicFiletrs = TopicFiletrs;
        
    }
```